# Adding custom Global action tab in the Lightning record page Activity composer

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, activities

I have a requirement to add a custom tab(create a new custom object record) in the activity composer along with new meeting, new to do and Email standard tabs.
 I was wondering if there is any possible way to add the custom global action on the activity composer?

Any Input is appreciated
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: According to documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=5 it looks like you can only add activity related actions to this tab (Event and Task, Log A Call and Send Email actions)

Comment: I know this is an old thread...but have you managed to solve this?

Comment: I have the same question, the documentation seems to insinuate that "Lighting Component" type Global Actions (Which are controlled by the _Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions_ section of _Page Layout_) appear in the *Highlights* panel of a Lightning Record Page - but the -Chatter- (Activity Composer? It's description is "Chatter publisher and the feed", though not a requirement that you use any Chatter here...) component renders only a subset of Global or Record Quick Actions. Documentation and guidance = FUBAR, IMOP.

Comment: One possibility: *Remove ALL "Activity" related Global/Object Quick Actions from Page Layout*, create a Custom Lightning Component and insert it into the Lightning Page _immediately_ above the *Activity Composer* (don't know what it's called anymore...)